# Bad request in Springboot custom filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-filters

When ever I try to get the request body inside the springboot filter (in order to check some parameters) a BAD request error is thrown

Here's the code for the filter

```
public class PostURLFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        InputStream requestInputStream = req.getInputStream();
        try {
            String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(requestInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            out.println(body + "this is the body");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }


        out.println("end");

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);


    }
}
```

This is my POST request body

```
{
       "id":590,
       "name":"run"
}
```

Without this piece of code (requesting the request body) the POST request works fine. But with this it doesn't run.

I don't know where I'm missing the login. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to debug? share your errors from log

Comment: Because you can only consume the body of the request once. You already consume it in the filter, there is nothing left for the controller to use and thus a bad request. You need to wrap your request in a `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` from that read the inputstream and pass the wrapped request along (instead of the original).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks buddy. I realised this issue now. thanks for the help